# What are the solutions to $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Psi + \frac{1}{x^2}\Psi - \frac{1}{x}\Psi = E\Psi$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, quantum-mechanics

Suppose that there exist some constant $E$ such that

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Psi + \frac{1}{x^2}\Psi - \frac{1}{x}\Psi = E\Psi$$

and suppose that $\Psi$ is of the form

$$\Psi = ke^{ax^b}$$

for some chosen constants $k, a, b$.

Then,

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Psi + \frac{1}{x^2}\Psi - \frac{1}{x}\Psi$$
$$=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(ke^{ax^b}) + \frac{1}{x^2}ke^{ax^b} - \frac{1}{x}ke^{ax^b}$$
$$=kab\frac{d}{dx}(x^{b-1}e^{ax^b}) + \frac{1}{x^2}ke^{ax^b} - \frac{1}{x}ke^{ax^b}$$

$$=kab(abx^{b-1}x^{b-1}e^{ax^b} + (b-1)x^{b-2}e^{ax^b}) + \frac{1}{x^2}ke^{ax^b} - \frac{1}{x}ke^{ax^b}$$
$$(a^2b^2x^{2b-2}+ ab(b-1)x^{b-2} + \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x})ke^{ax^b}$$
$$=E\Psi$$

Is there a clever choice of constants $a, b$ such that

$$a^2b^2x^{2b-2}+ ab(b-1)x^{b-2} + \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x} = E$$

can just be a constant number $E$ (with all its $x$ dependence removed)?

Alternatively, can there be other forms of $\Psi$ that can be a solution to this equation?

Comment: No such $a,b$ exist and I'll tell you why: $a^2b^2$ is always nonnegative so your only hope for matching degree terms to cancel out is if there exists some $b$ such that $2b-2=-1$ and $b-2=-2$. But no such $b$ exists. I haven't tested it myself but adding the extra degree of freedom you need in that system of equations, in the form of a solution $x^ce^{ax^b}$, may be worth a shot.

Comment: @Gonçalo. This is as good as an answer, if you wrote it up explicitly for the OP...